# ProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility reappears on change rotation

Tags: android

i have a problem with my app. if i click the button to stop the ProgressBarIndeterminate in actionbar, when i rotate the screen it reappear. can i stop it forever? thanks

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

}

public void test(View v) {
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
}
```

sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rotate your screen, the Activity gets created again (`onCreate` will get invoked again), so you will call `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true)` which will make it reappear.

To keep track of whether or not you've clicked the stop button, you will need to save the state somehow (consider implementing `onSaveInstanceState` and then retrieving the stored value in `onCreate`, or saving the state to a shared preference/database).

`onSaveInstanceState` --> invoked when your Activity is torn down due to the rotation

```
private boolean showProgressBarVisibility = true; //always show the first time 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("user3744384_pressed_the_button"){
       showProgressBarVisibility = false
    }

    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(showProgressBarVisibility);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("user3744384_pressed_the_button", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like this in onCreate:

```
if(savedInstanceState !=null){

 setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
}
```

but you should also save the state in `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle ...)`.. research on how activities save their state.

Answer (score 0):

when orientation changes android kills your activity and onCreate is called.. you can save your app state and restore it.

override this method to save state

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    savedInstanceState.putString(key, yourstatevariable);

}
```

and get your state variable in onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);

if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        String yourstatevariable = savedInstanceState.get(key);

    }

}
```